# Wearing black on Sabbath

Tags: shabbat, minhag

On the Sabbath it is a custom to wear white.

Is it fine to wear black underwear on Shabbath, as long as your outer garment is white?

Comment: Why should it not be okay? The Rabbeinu Bahya says "Under normal circumstances outer garments remain outer garments and underwear remains underwear.". It is a Minhag to wear white garments. I do not think underwear falls into the same category?

Comment: What's the source for your claim that there is a minhag to wear white on Shabbos? I never heard of there being anything wrong with wearing black on Shabbos. In fact I know many people who wear a black hat and suit/kapoteh to shul on Shabbos.

Comment: What is your source for your first assertion? I know lots of religious people who whear white shirts during the week, and lots of religious people who wear blue shirts on Shabbat.

Comment: Rabbi Chaim Vital is my source

Comment: @RaulValdezJr. then it would be better to note this in your question since that custom is by far not universally practiced

Answer (score 5):

The premise of your question is a little bit confusing. Most religious Jews do not follow this custom. However, some do.

One of the sources for this custom is the Arizal, brought in the [Siddur of R’ Yaakov Emden](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&st=&pgnum=672) (number 17) in which he says that one should wear 4 white garments. Beyond that, he says you should try to have all garments special for shabbos but the color doesn’t seem to matter.

The [Kaf Hachaim 262:24](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.262.24.1?lang=bi) clarifies further exactly which 4 garments should be white, and states explicitly that under garments are not included;

> ודע כי אין לפחות מן ד' בגדי לבן והם המלבוש העליון והתחתון והאזור אשר על לבושו התחתון והחלוק אשר על בשרו. והאר"י ז"ל בימי החורף ביום שבת היה לובש מפני הצנה מלבוש א' של בגדי ארגמן תחת המלבוש הלבן העליון ולא היה חושש רק לשיהיו לו ד' בגדי לבן כנז' ומספר ד' בגדים אלו הם כנגד ד' אותיות הוי"ה. ואלו הם סוד בגדי עולם הבריאה והם בחי' אור המקיף מבחוץ כנז' בברכת מלביש ערומים יעו"ש. שער הכוו' דף ס"ג ע"א. פע"ח שער ח"י פ"ד

The [Beer Heitiv 262:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Ba%27er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.262.4?lang=bi) also mentions these 4 garments only

The [Biur Halacha in siman 262](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.262.2.1?lang=bi) however rules that if it looks like haughtiness, one shouldn’t do it and proves that the Amorim wore black as well

> בגדים נאים - ולבישת בגד לבן בשבת אם מחזי כיוהרא לא יעשה ובא"ר הביא ראיה מהגמרא דרבנן לבשו גלימי אוכמי בשבת עי"ש. ובביתו רשאי אדם לעשות מה שירצה לא בפני רבים [פמ"ג]

Comment: Does it matter which four? Say, undershirt, underwear, and two socks?

Comment: @magicker72 I’ve edited the answer to include your question

Comment: It’s the 4 garments of that day I assume

Comment: @Raul Valdez Jr. Know that the minimum is to wear four white garments, these are the outer garment, the lower garment, the sash upon one’s lower garments and the robe that is [worn] upon the skin.

Comment: 4 outer Garments?

Comment: @Chatzkel Could it be that today's undershirt is like החלוק אשר על בשרו? And I wonder why the Talit Katan is not mentioned which is anyway white.. was it worn inside or outside this chiluk?

Comment: I would think the shirt is the chaluk. I think the 4 begadim are representing the 4 bigdei kehuna which explains why the tzitzis won’t count

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some more sources, origin and context:

Tikunei Zohar daf 78b:

```
בראשית ברא אלקי"ם, פתח ואמר כשושנה בין החוחים וכו', שושנה אית לה חמש עלין מלגו וחמש עלין מלבר, ואינון ה"ה, שרביט דילה ו', תפוח דילה י', וכלא אלקי"ם, חמש אתוון דיליה ה' חמש עלין מלבר, ה' חמש עלין מלגאו, י' תפוח ו', מל"א שרביט:

בזמנא דהאי שושנה איהי בגלותא איהי אטומא, בזמנא דיהא פורקנא בעלמא אתפתחת בחמש אור, הדא הוא דכתיב ויאמר אלקי"ם יהי אור, ובההוא זמנא דאתפתחת אתלבשת בכמה לבושין דנהורין דאורייתא, ואתקשטת בכמה קשוטין דפקודין דעשה, ובזמנא דאתפתחת ואתקשטת בקשוטהא, בארבעה בגדי לבן דאינון יקו"ק, ובארבעה בגדי זהב דאינון אדנ"י, בארבע בתי דתפילין דיד, ובארבע בתי דתפילין דרישא, דאינון לקבלייהו, ארבע לבושין דכהן הדיוט אינון לקבל ארבע כנפות כסותך אשר תכסה בה:

וכד אתתקנת באלין לבושין, מיד אתפתח היכלא לגבה, הדא הוא דכתיב אדנ"י שפתי תפתח, ולקול נעימו דרמונים וזוגין דלבושא דילה, אתמר בחיוון ואשמע את קול כנפיהם, וכד אמרין ישראל קריאת שמע, מה כתיב בה (במדבר ז') וישמע את הקול מדבר אליו, קלא אשתמע לגבה מבין תרין כרוביא דאינון דו פרצופין, וכד מתייחדא דבור בקלא אתעבידו קול דממה דקה, ודא צלותא בחשאי, ובההוא זמנא מאן דבעי למשאל שאלתוי ישאל, דבההיא זמנא יהא עת רצון, דהא תרין שמהן כחדא יאקדונק"י, אז תקרא וה' יענה, מיד א"ז יאקדונק"י, תרין שמהן ותמניא אתוון דבהון הא עשר, (ודא רזא ארור אשר לא יקים את דברי התורה הזאת וכו', דא חבורא דחתן:
```

...
When that Rose (the Shekhina; Yisrael) is in the Exile she is closed. At the time when Redemption comes in the world she opens in five Ohr/light, behold it's the scripture, "And ELKY"M said Y"HY OHR."
And at that time when she opens she is dressed in abundant garments of the lights of the Torah, and ornamented with abundant jewelry of the positive commandments.
And when she opens and is ornamented, with the **four white garments** which are YKW"K, and four golden garments which are ADN"Y, with four houses of the hand Tefilin, and four houses of head Tefilin, which correspond to them; four garments of the deputy Kohen correspond to the (Deut. 22:12, tallit) "four wings of your garment with which you cover yourself." And immediately when she's fixed with these garments, the Heikhal opens to her, behold it's the scripture, "ADN"Y open my lips" ..."

BTW Where the BIH also mentions that men should wear four white garments I think he also mentioned women should wear four golden garments accordingly [add source].

And regarding black, the Baal Shem Tov is said to have said not to wear black on Shabbat [add source] - but this might also or alternatively be taken as staying far from melancholy and sadness.

Comment: Today it would be the normal 4 clothing no?

Comment: @RaulValdezJr. See above in Chatzkel answer, Kaf haChayim says the suit top, suit bottom, the waistband around the suit bottom, and the tunic against his body. Main difference in today's western wear is maybe the belt doesn't have as much importance as the eastern waistband, so idk. I have friends that go with a white Kipa - but they don't have a suit top and their pants aren't white.  Sometimes the kavana may suffice or at least help - you have the intention of the 4 garments (even if some might be the talit katan or the undergarments, though not ideal).

Comment: Thank you sir, I appreciate the answer